# I am using log4j 1.2.12 on a maven project, but it isn't displaying 'debug' messages. How can I resolve this?

Tags: eclipse, maven, log4j

I am using log4j 1.2.12 and maven doesn't seem to be detecting the log4jproperties file
Here is my folder structure:
[image]

Here is my log4j.properties:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Yet it still cannot be detected.

Comment: it looks good so far. is there anything in your pom that would change how maven works with the resources folder? and how do you run the project? using maven or some eclipse run configuration (that may not include the resources folder?)

Comment: I run it from eclipse. Eclipse has a run as maven option

Comment: so how is it not detected? is there a warning or error? does the ecplise config contain the resources folder into the classpath? and why are you using such an old logging library?

Comment: Nothing appears on the console. 'info' messages appear on the console though.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue, it seems we weren't using log4j but using log4j2. They have different configurations, which is why I cannot see any debug messages.